# Iterating 2d array

Tags: java, matrix, iterator

I have implemented a `MatrixIt` class to traverse a 2D array. Is it possible to make the code clearer and shorter?

```
public class MatrixIt implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private final int[][] data;
    private int row = 0;
    private int column = 0;

    public MatrixIt(int[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        while (row < data.length && data[row].length == column) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        }
        return row < data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return data[row][column++];
    }
}
```

Comment: The `while` in your `hasNext` method could probably be changed to a simple `if` statement

Comment: How do you expect your `hasNext()` and `next()` methods to behave? How do you define traversal in context of a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the thing that most facilitates a simple row-wise iterator is to arrange the storage in the same format that we'll iterate.

Instead of having an array of references to per-row arrays, representing a matrix by a single linear array is a good choice: faster to create, and with better memory locality:

```
public class Matrix {
    private int[] data;
    int width;
    int height;

    int get(int x, int y) {
        return data[y * width + x];
    }

    void set(int x, int y, int value) {
        data[y * width + x] = value;
    }
}
```

Then the iterator can be a simple (linear) iterator over the `data`.